# How to print Specific key value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

for key,value in fruit.items():
     print(value)
```

I want to print the kiwi key, how?

```
print(value[2])
```

This is not working.

Comment: you need 'kiwi' string to fetch its corresponding **value** from the dict. 'kiwi' string is itself key, why not just do `print('kiwi')`? If you want to fetch key based on index, in older version of Python's dictionary were unordered in nature. However from Python 3.6, they maintain the insertion order.

Comment: if you are looking for printing the value of "kiwi" key, then you need to just do `fruit["kiwi"]`

Comment: `print(fruit['kiwi'])`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri See my ans

Comment: @VasilisG. See my ans

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's too late but none of the answer mentioned about [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method

```
>>> print(fruit.get('kiwi'))
2.0
```

In `dict.get()` method you can also pass default value if key not exist in the dictionary it will return default value. If default value is not specified then it will return `None`.

```
>>> print(fruit.get('cherry', 99))
99
```

`fruit` dictionary doesn't have key named `cherry` so `dict.get()` method returns default value `99`

Answer (score 28):

Python's dictionaries **have no order**, so indexing like you are suggesting (`fruits[2]`) makes no sense as you can't retrieve the second element of something that has no order. They are merely sets of `key:value` pairs.

To retrieve the value at `key`: `'kiwi'`, simply do: `fruit['kiwi']`. This is the most fundamental way to access the value of a certain key. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for further clarification.

And passing that into a `print()` call would actually give you an output:

```
print(fruit['kiwi'])
#2.0
```

---

*Note how the `2.00` is reduced to `2.0`, this is because superfluous zeroes are removed.*

---

Finally, if you want to use a `for-loop` (don't know why you would, they are significantly more inefficient in this case  (`O(n)` vs `O(1)` for straight lookup)) then you can do the following:

```
for k, v in fruit.items():
    if k == 'kiwi':
        print(v)
#2.0
```

Answer (score 15):

```
fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

for key,value in fruit.items():
    if value == 2.00:
         print(key)
```

I think you are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

EASY PEASY LEMON SQUEEZY
You can access the key without knowing the name of the key just with the index of a list.
Make all the keys a list and then look for the index number you want of the keys.

```
tell_me_why = {
'You': 56,
'Are': 23,
'My': 43,
'Fire': 78,
'The': 11,
"One":10,
'Desire':8,
'Belive':6,
'When':134,
'I':1234,
'Say':77,
"I Want":123,
'It':12345,
"That":123211,
'Way':12345
}
#make the keys a list
tell_me_why_keys = list(tell_me_why.keys())
#print the list of the keys
print(tell_me_why_keys)
#print certain key
print(tell_me_why_keys[5])
#print certain key value
print(tell_me_why[tell_me_why_keys[5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the value of key 'kiwi' with

```
print(fruit['kiwi'])
```

Comment: but no loop :) i use for

Comment: @lrakli I understood  the question to be "how to print just the one value out of the `dict`.  If that is not what you are looking for, then you should reword the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print by using below command

```
print(fruit['kiwi'])
```

If you want to check whether a key has been successfully added or not, use below command:

```
print('key' in dictionary)
```

> for eg: `print('New york' in USA)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

for key in fruit:
     print(fruit[key],"=",key)
```

Comment: No Bro i want to print only kiwi value

Comment: @Irakli check my new answer.

Comment: @AbhisekRoy Delete your answer if it is wrong! Even though it has an upvote, sometimes you must accept the fate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display the Kiwi field.

```
fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

print(fruit["kiwi"],"=kiwi")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

list_keys = []
list_values = []

for value in fruit.keys():
    list_keys.append(value)

for value in fruit.values():
    list_values.append(value)

print(list_keys)
print(list_values)

for value_ipos,value_item in enumerate(list_keys):
    if value_item == "kiwi":
        print(value_item,list_values[value_ipos])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
def reverse_dict(dictionary, lookup_val):
    for key,value in fruit.items():
        if abs(lookup_val-value) < 0.01:
            return key

fruit = {
    "banana": 1.00,
    "apple": 1.53,
    "kiwi": 2.00,
    "avocado": 3.23,
    "mango": 2.33,
    "pineapple": 1.44,
    "strawberries": 1.95,
    "melon": 2.34,
    "grapes": 0.98
}

for key,value in fruit.items():
    print("{}:{}".format(key, value))

print(fruit['kiwi'])
print(reverse_dict(fruit, 2.00))
```

Many reasons for caution

1. This will get slow with a large dict
2. only first match will be returned
3. your value is a float, so a tolerance is needed: I picked 0.01

Answer (score -1):

```
favorite_numbers = {'jacob': 5, 'christine': 12, 'opiyo': 13, 'jeremy': 27, 'dingo': 36}
```

print("Here is each individual's favorite number:")

print('jacob'.title() + ": " + str(favorite_numbers['jacob']))
print('christine'.title() + ": " + str(favorite_numbers['christine']))

Comment: This example will help you make sense of what you are looking for.