# How to print a specific list?

Tags: python, list

I would like to print a specific row from my list;
"1. McDonalds       ": "Mon to Sat: 7am to 12am, Sun & PH: 10am to 10pm"

```
StoreOpTime = {
"1. McDonalds       ": "Mon to Sat: 7am to 12am, Sun & PH: 10am to 10pm",
"2. Subway          ": "Mon to Fri: 8am to 9pm, Sat & Sun: 11am to 6pm",
"3. KFC             ": "Mon to Fri: 7.30am to 10pm, Sat & Sun: 11am to 8pm",
"4. Fun World Cafe  ": "Mon to Fri: 8am to 8pm, Sat: 9am to 3​pm",}
StoreList = list(StoreOpTime.keys())  # to get the list of the store only
```

---

```
for x, y in StoreOpTime.items():
            print(x, ":", y)
```

Prints the whole list.

---

```
for x, y in StoreOpTime.items():
            print(x[0], ":", y[0]) #print Mcdonalds operating hours
```

Prints just the first letter from the list I want

---

```
print(StoreList[0])
```

Prints just "1. McDonalds       "

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Specific key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894060/how-to-print-specific-key-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need a element that will match in only one fast-food key, then use it, like the number or example

```
number = input("Choose a fast-food number in [1:4]")
for x, y in StoreOpTime.items():
    if x.startswith(number):
        print(x, ":", y)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the StoreList both as the StoreName and the index to get the OpTime for that store.

```
print{f'{StoreList[0]}:{StoreOpTime[StoreList[0]]}'
```

Tho you should not use a Python Dict for this, as it is an unordered datastruct.